# yii framework in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii

In my web application I am unable to change to friendly url's. In some blogs I read that it is done by changing the main.php file and  editing the .htaccess file. But I am unable to find the .htaccess file anywhere .I also tried by editing the /etc/apache2/sites-available/default . But it did not work. Can Anyone help me with this?. the name of my application is 'electrical'.
My  /etc/apache2/sites-available/default file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www/electrical
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/electrical>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

My code for the protected/config/main.php

```
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
                    'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

I want to use friendly Urls such as localhost/electrical/home, /index etc .Please Help me, Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache, you have to create the `.htaccess` file in the folder that has the entry script (the main index.php file). The contents of the `.htaccess` file should be:

**Update**: Changed the `.htaccess` rules to what is mentioned in the official Yii docs:

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

as mentioned in this wiki: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/53/using-search-engine-and-user-friendly-urls/

Also change the `default` file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` to also contain this:

```
<Directory /var/www/> <--- ***root directory***
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all <---- ***important***
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: I tried that but does not work  ,it says "ERROR 404"  unable to resolve the request .

Comment: Try modifying the `.htaccess` file by removing the two lines: `<IfModule ...>` and `</IfModule>` and see what is showing... maybe the rewrite module is not installed on your server? If so it will throw a server error after you have done this...

Comment: it says the same... "ERROR 404"  .unable to resolve the request.

Comment: Please see the edits i made in my answer... Also does the homepage work without errors? Is it only other page urls that are broken? The only other thing i can think of to do is run `a2enmod rewrite` to enable the rewrite module in apache...